# How we can install and uninstall gcc in linux redhat using command?

Tags: linux, gcc

i want to install and uninstall GCC using command.
How can i do that.

any idea?

Answer (score 8):

Please run the following in command line:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove --skip-broken gcc

sudo apt-get install --skip-broken gcc
```

Centos:

```
sudo yum remove --skip-broken gcc

sudo yum install --skip-broken gcc
```