# How to completely remove gcc from CentOS 7

Tags: linux, gcc, centos7

I'm trying to downgrade my gcc from 7.4 to 7.3 but I'm unable to delete it.

I tried the following command with no luck. It removes 4.8.5 but not 7.4.

```
sudo yum remove gcc
```

I tried  `make uninstall` in the gcc dir. It said that

> the uninstall target is not supported in this tree

I tried also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705429/how-we-can-install-and-uninstall-gcc-in-linux-redhat-using-command) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687351/uninstalling-gcc) but with no luck.

Comment: You do not want to remove the installed version of gcc. Most of your system and the libraries installed depend on a specific version of glibc. You can see [How to use multiple versions of GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448457/3422102) and hopefully accomplish what you are trying to do in a sane manner.